# Excel multiple IF statements, AND statement, and MONTH function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on an excel sheet where I have a month and year value stored in cell `D3` as text, this is a start date. The cell contents look like "January 2018". Additionally, in cell `F3`, I have the end dates which are stored as text. The cell contents look like "April 2018".

The formula I am hoping to build will create a space if `D3` is equal to the month of July or if `D3` is less than July and F3 is greater than July.

The current formula looks like this:

```
=IF(MONTH(D3)=6," ", IF (AND(MONTH(D3)<6,(MONTH(F3>6))," ",)))
```

Any recommendations to get the desired outcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe*:

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(D3)=7,AND(MONTH(D3)<7,MONTH(F3)>7))," ")
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!